# Mongodb lookup with localfield $in foreignfield

Tags: mongodb, next.js, lookup

I have tags collection and products collections. Tags have tag names while products have multiple tags save in array. I want to apply join on tags and get all the records from dishes collection where tag name  from tags collection exists in tags array of dishes.
i want something like this

```
const tag = await Tag.
  aggregate([
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'products',
         localField: 'name',
         foreignField: { tag :{ $in :'name'}},
         as: 'tagsdetails'
       }
     }
    ]);
```

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MycrCAKyeDp) what are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what i want.